# How to launch application not from console in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I'm developing application with Ubuntu Touch. I use QML and C++ plugin. I can launch the application from console using "qmlscene -I ./imports myApp.qml", but when I add new desktop file, wherein I write it must run my bash script, launching application, it not working. I see just white screen, when I push the button.

If I launch pure QML application, all works well. I think problem is in my C++ plugin.

I want to launch my application directly from phone, without use of adb or ssh in my desktop.

Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we've been doing this with the Core Apps is to package the C++ plugin separately, and make that package a dependency of your app's package.  Then you don't need the `-I`.  We also use `qmlscene /path/to/app.qml` directly in the .desktop file's Exec line.